# How do I handle a NULL in a VueJS filter?

Tags: vue.js

The following filter works

```
    filteredItems() {
        return this.items.filter(item => 
                item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1)

    }
```

However, when I try to filter on a second column, I have 2 issue

```
return this.items.filter(item => 
item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1)
.filter(item => 
item.location.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1)
```

First issue, sometimes location is NULL, so the page won't load. To test, I updated the nulls to blank values in the database, and the page has no errors.

Second, I can't search by location (even when null set to blanks)

***** EDIT****
It seems it requires both filters to be true... so I will check docs on that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can check for invalid values like `null, undefined, ""` and safely search by `name` OR `location`. Here is an example:

```js
function filteredItems() {
  return this.items
   .filter(item => {
     return (item.name && item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1) || 
    (item.location && item.location.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1) 
   }) 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `||` operator to add either use `name` or `location` filters like:

```
filteredItems() {
  var search = this.search.toLowerCase();
  return this.items.filter(({name = '', location = ''}) => {
    return name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1 || name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) > -1;
  })
}
```

and to resolve the `null` issue you can set an empty string as a default value to `name` & `location` like `({name = '', location = ''})`